# COuldn't load okta signin widget in .net framework 4.5.1 in internet explorer 11

Tags: vb.net, okta

COuldn't load okta signin widget  in internet explorer 11 in .net framework 4.5. where as it is working fine in chrome. could you please help

Comment: https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Miscellaneous/Platforms_Browser_OS_Support.htm.  Does look like IE11 still supported to some degree, but why would be concerned with a now obsolete browser?

Comment: have you added the [polyfills](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#browser-compatibility--polyfill) to your login page for ie11/edge support?